# removing dependencies.dependency.version errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working with a mavenised java project in Eclipse with several modules which fails to build throwing the error from the pom file:

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for cml:jumbo-converters-molecule-xyz:jar is missing.
```

These errors relate to the sub-modules. They do not carry version numbers. It does not happen for all cases of submodules

Does this mean I have to add version numbers to all pom files and all references in pom files? Or can I add something which neglects the version number until I get it built?

Answer (score 13):

You need to add a `dependencyManagement` section to the parent POM, and specify version numbers there. See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_dependencyManagement

Comment: +1 for contributing. It doesn't really address my problem but I think that's because I inherited a project I didn't understand and my hacking has broken it. Have struggled back to somewhere close to working

Comment: I've never had to add this before, but in a new project I'm setting up it would not resolve and this was why . . . no idea why my other projects all work without it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the groupid differed between the parent pom (dependencyManagement) and child pom (dependency).

Comment: This was true in my case also, the parent pom had a dependencyMgmt section under which default version was set... and it was not set for this particular dependency...